# Xamarin image renderer from byte[]

Tags: arrays, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, queue, uwp-xaml

I am building an application in which I implement stream using singalR.
I used this code example to get image from the camera of one contact https://github.com/Guille1878/VideoChat (thanks to him for providing such a code).

I updated the protocol by sending to the hub a json:

```
string arrayJson = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(array);
```

When the image arrived in the client receiver, I will return it as byte[] using the following code:

```
hubConnection.On<string>("DownloadStream", (streamJson) =>
{
    byte[] stream = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<byte[]>(streamJson);
    MyClass.StreamVideoArray.Enqueue(stream);
});
```

To use the image, I created a dependency interface launch for now with a button:

```
private async void StartStopStream_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (onStreaming)
    {
        onStreaming = false;
        OnStreamStatus.Text = "Stream terminated";
    }
    else
    {
        onStreaming = true;
        OnStreamStatus.Text = "On stream";
    }
    int count = 0;
    while (onStreaming)
    {
        await DependencyService.Get<IStreamImgConvert>().BuildImageFrames(count++);
        Stream1 = App.StreamImage;
    }
}
```

Inside the injection I used the following code:

```
public async Task BuildImageFrames(int count)
{
    await Task.Delay(5);

    MyClass.StreamVideoArray.TryDequeue(out byte[] buffer);

    if (!(buffer?.Any() ?? false))
        return;

    try
    {
        var imageMemoryStream = new MemoryStream(buffer);
        \\Create a new filepath using the int count
        string filePath = Path.Combine(FileSystem.AppDataDirectory, $"File{count}.bmp");

        \\Create the image to ensure the byte arrays from the buffer is usable
        File.WriteAllBytes(filePath, buffer); 
        ImageSource imgFromStream = ImageSource.FromStream(() => imageMemoryStream);

        \\Update the static image which should be update in the xaml page
        MyClass.StreamImage.Source = imgFromStream; 
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(ex.Message);
    }
}
```

the **int count** inside BuildImageFrames() is used to create image. Thoses images are created perfectly. Unfortunately the byte[] do not used to create a static image does not display any image inside the xaml page.

I wonder if it is possible to create something like that. Can someone help me to figured it out?

May be provide another solution to use the Queue<byte[]> to show the stream.

Comment: there are numerous [existing questions](https://www.google.com/search?q=xamarin+image+byte[]+site:stackoverflow.com) about creating an Image from a byte[]

Answer (score 0):

Thank you @jason for the link.
By looking at it, it reminds me that to manipulate an object inside a xaml, it should be done inside the xaml, the xaml.cs of MVVM binded to the page.

I corrected my code and was able to display the image. Inside the Dependency injection I used the following code:

```
public async Task BuildImageFrames(int count)
{
    await Task.Delay(5);

    MyClass.App.StreamVideoArray.TryDequeue(out byte[] buffer);

    if (!(buffer?.Any() ?? false))
        return;

    try
    {
        MyClass.App.VideoArray = buffer;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(ex.Message);
    }
}
```

And inside the xaml page, I used the following code:

```
int count = 0;
while (onStreaming)
{
    await DependencyService.Get<IStreamImgConvert>().BuildImageFrames(count++);
    if (App.VideoArray != null)
    {
        ImageSource imgFromStream = ImageSource.FromStream(() => new MemoryStream(App.VideoArray));
        Stream1.Source = imgFromStream;
    }
}
```